# Accessing response using java in playframework

Tags: java, playframework

How to access `Response` object in Java?

I have gone through the documentation:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaResponse

But the problem with the above documentation is that I don't know what to import. What class I have to import to access and manipulate `Response`s?

Comment: It's a method of the Controller class from Play (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/mvc/Controller.html). You have to extend your controller class with Controller to access this method.

Comment: Have a look at these docs from Play https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaActions

Comment: Thanks.. extending the controller from play.mvc.Controller worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the following class:

```
import play.mvc.Result;
```

This is usually already imported when you create a new project using [Activator](https://www.lightbend.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt).